# Undefined control sequence

Tags: math-mode

On this code:

```
$t = \plusminus \sqrt{\frac{2,7}{4,9}} \approx \plusminus 0,74$
```

I get the message `Undefined control sequence`. What have I forgotten?

Comment: `\plusminus`should be replaced with `\pm`.

Comment: My dear friend, no offense, but this is the third question of this kind within the last 10 minutes. Maybe you need a nap... `:)`

Comment: It seems a bit cruel to give someone a negative vote:  particularly if they're new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume you're a bit new to LaTeX.

Suppose you have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$t = \plusminus \sqrt{\frac{2,7}{4,9}} \approx \plusminus 0,74$

\end{document}
```

and then you try to compile it.  You'll get the following error.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 $t = \plusminus
                    \sqrt{\frac{2,7}{4,9}} \approx \plusminus 0,74$
?
```

There are three pieces of information here that are relevant to you figuring out what's happening.

The first is `! Undefined control sequencve.`  That tells you the most likely reason for the error.  The second and third are on the second line  `l.5 $t = \plusminus`.  The `1.5` tells you the line.  (If you load or input various different files, you can sometimes determine which file  by carefully reading the `log` file to see which file LateX most recently examined.)  At the end of this same line is `\plusminus` and then a carriage return.  This is the most likely *undefined* control sequence that you're trying to identify.

I would suggest that you try either doing a web search on **latex plusminus** or refer to `symbols-a4.pdf` which should be included with your LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `$\pm$` instead of `$\plusminus$`.

Comment: Just for additional information: There is no `\am`.